# I can't configure multiple nginx server blocks

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mariadb, subdirectory

I recently installed nginx and php7.0 on my raspberry pi 3 (Raspbian Stretch) and I couldn't configure the server configuration files. Here is information of nginx and php:

```
$ sudo nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3

$ sudo php -v
PHP 7.0.30-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2018 13:50:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.30-0+deb9u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Here is my server configuration file:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/example

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    include global/restrictions.conf;

    # Root
    location / {
        root /var/www/root/html;
        index index.php index.htm index.html index.nginx-debian.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        include global/root.conf;
    }


    # WordPress
    location /blog/ {
        root /var/www/blog/html;
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        include global/wordpress.conf;
    }

    # DokuWiKi
    location /wiki/ {
        root /var/www/wiki/html;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        include global/wiki.conf;
    }

    # NextCloud
    # location /drive/ {
        # root /var/www/drive/html;
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        # include global/.conf;
    # }

}
```

(nextcloud is not configured yet.)

/etc/nginx/global/root.conf & /etc/nginx/global/wiki.conf
(Those two files have same contents)

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

/etc/nginx/global/wordpress.conf

```
# WordPress single site rules. Designed to be included in any
# server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if
# rules below fail. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location /blog/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error
# logging.
location ~*
^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$
{
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching
#plugin (if used). include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and
    # works with "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" in /etc/php.ini (default)

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}


# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess,
# .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac). Keep logging the requests to parse
# later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads
# directory Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite
# network Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to
# firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

I configured this way because:

A. I can apply different configuration on each subdirectory. (I don't want to show wordpress' 404 page on nextcloud)

B. I can just include overlapping configuration file by including global configuration.conf

The problem is:

A. The server won't even show files in each subdirectory. It's showing nginx welcome page on root (which I removed), and won't show files under subdirectory (e.g. "example.com/wiki" which is in "/var/www/wiki/html" would just show me 404 page)

B. I don't think php is configured correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install php-fpm and it will resolve your issue

Command to install php-fpm version 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

Comment: Already installed onㄷ. And that's not the problem. It won't show up any webpages in each subdirectory. (Root folder of each location block thing)

Comment: You can check whether installed or not by php-fpm -v

Comment: Checked and it's the latest.